# Smooth ListLinePlot with missing elements in list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider the following list:

```
{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4}}
```

Plotting with `ListLinePlot` gives a smooth linear curve.

How can the list be plotted smoothly if it were

```
{{1,1},{2,2},{},{4,4}}
```

In matlab there is an option to replace any missing elements with `NaN` and the plot command ignores these entries.

Here `ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {NaN, NaN}, {3, 3}}, PlotRange -> All]` cut the plot before (or after) the `NaN` values.

How can the missing entries be ignored while keeping the list as it is (i.e, not removing `{}`)

Comment: `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {}, {4, 4}} /. {} -> Nothing // ListLinePlot`  ?

Comment: Since the plotter will remove `{}`/`{NaN, NaN}` internally from the graphics, I don't see a reason for objecting to removing it beforehand.  For instance, with `ListLinePlot[
 Cases[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}], PlotRange -> All]`.